# How are Vdc and M1 influencing the circuit in this voltage controlled oscillator?

Tags: oscillator, cmos

I have simulated a VCO and I want to understand the difference between the ring oscillator.

[image]

In this case I have a higher frequency than in ring oscillator with same parameters of transistors. I think that V1 and M1 are influencing the circuit such that we will have lower \$t\$ in the frequency equation $$f = \frac{1}{2tn}$$ hence we will decrease the frequency.
I don't understand how \$V_{\text{DC}}\$ and M1 are influencing the circuit.

Comment: A ring oscillator is a voltage controlled oscillator.

Comment: Here is a similar illogical question: What is the difference between a banana and a fruit?

Comment: @HarrySvensson I want to understand how V1 and M1 influence the circuit.

Comment: @VahramVoskerchyan Your question definitely reflected that.

Comment: @HarrySvensson yes I agree, my question was stupid. And doesn't show what I was interested to ask.

Comment: Higher VDD produces higher transconductance, and that produces a faster stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ring oscillator is to daffodil, as voltage controlled oscillator is to yellow flower.

A ring oscillator is an odd-numbered ring of inverter gates that forms an oscillator.

A voltage controlled oscillator is *any* oscillator whose frequency can be controlled by altering a voltage. For instance there are many types of LC oscillators, where the C uses a varactor diode. Another type is where a voltage controls a current that charges a capacitor, which starts the next cycle when a threshold is reached. There's another class of oscillator where a fixed ramp is compared against a voltage to start the next cycle. And there are probably a few more types as well.

In your particular circuit, if M2 source was returned to ground and M1 not present, that would be what most people would describe as a 'ring oscillator'. It is usually one of the first test circuits to be built on a new process, as it demonstrates the maximum possible frequency that inverters can switch. Just the ring of gates can be controlled in frequency by varying the supply voltage, which changes the drive strength of the outputs, and the capacitance of the junctions forming the gates, the junctions behave just like varactors.

With V1 and M1 added, the frequency can be controlled as M1 limits the current available into M2, which limits the rate at which M2 can discharge the M2/3/4/5 node. This controlled oscillator will run at a lower frequency than one without the control.

Comment: Thanks. But for instance, how V1 and M1 nmos transistor influence  the circuit.

Comment: Looks like they change the low voltage available at M2, which changes the rate at which the capacitance at M2/3/4/5 node can be discharged. This control mechanism is more like my #2 version, where the control voltage alters the current that can discharge that junction capacitance.

Answer (score 0):

As V1 increases and W/L of M1 keeps constant, the frequency increases.
This happens because V1 is the gate voltage of M1 and when it increases the current will also increase and the delay of the first stage will become smaller, hence we will have higher frequency 
As we keep V1 constant and change the W/L ration the frequency will also go high.
This is because the delay of the first stage becomes smaller, so the frequency goes higher.